# Postgresql Can't filter a query using sum of field

Tags: postgresql, sum, where-clause

actually I need get all the rows that have a SUM(row) > 0, but when I make the sentence and execute it:

```
select o.corden,
    o.cproveedor,
    o.fecha_orden,
    o.status,
    o.monto_total,
    SUM(od.cant_restante) as cant_pend,
    COUNT(od.cart_comercial) as articulos,
    d.nombre as proveedor
from ordencompra o
inner join ordencompra_det od on o.corden = od.corden_det
inner join proveedores p on o.cproveedor = p.cproveedor
inner join data d on p.cdata = d.cdata
where o.status = 'PROCESADA'
    and cant_pend > 0
group by o.corden,
    d.nombre
order by o.corden asc
```

it said: **The column << cant_pend >> doesn't exist!**
So i change it to:

```
select o.corden,
    o.cproveedor,
    o.fecha_orden,
    o.status,
    o.monto_total,
    SUM(od.cant_restante) as cant_pend,
    COUNT(od.cart_comercial) as articulos,
    d.nombre as proveedor
from ordencompra o
inner join ordencompra_det od on o.corden = od.corden_det
inner join proveedores p on o.cproveedor = p.cproveedor
inner join data d on p.cdata = d.cdata
where o.status = 'PROCESADA'
    and SUM(od.cant_restante) > 0
group by o.corden,
    d.nombre
order by o.corden asc
```

**agregate function's can't be allowed on where clausule**

Any help with the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `having` clause:

```
select o.corden,
    o.cproveedor,
    o.fecha_orden,
    o.status,
    o.monto_total,
    SUM(od.cant_restante) as cant_pend,
    COUNT(od.cart_comercial) as articulos,
    d.nombre as proveedor
from ordencompra o
inner join ordencompra_det od on o.corden = od.corden_det
inner join proveedores p on o.cproveedor = p.cproveedor
inner join data d on p.cdata = d.cdata
where o.status = 'PROCESADA'
group by o.corden,
    d.nombre
having SUM(od.cant_restante) > 0
order by o.corden asc
```

Comment: Is exactly what i just need it! Thanks :)

Comment: Any difference between have the sql queries in mayus or minus?

Comment: @JuJoGuAl - Sorry? I didn't understand what you just asked.

Comment: Any difference between have the sql queries in uppercase or lowercase* ?

Comment: Depend on programer. I put all keywords in `UPPER CASE` rest is lower case to make it easy to read. But doesnt make different to the db

Comment: @JuJoGuAl - It is a matter of preference. Doesn't matter as long as the query does what it's supposed to.

Comment: btw, that query wont work because not all field on the SELECT are in the aggregated section.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Not sure about this case but what you say is not [necessarily true for Postgresql](http://rextester.com/RIZFG62365). If the columns on which the aggregation is being done as PKs then the rest of the columns from the table are not required to be listed in group by - an awesome feature.

Comment: The query work with the Gurv's answers, and i just asked because Gurv edited all my code!